# Conditions for the series to converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

Find $\alpha > 0$ so that the following series converges.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think these three terms define the series well enough, it's not completely clear how the terms progress.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Also, assuming that the series given is of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\alpha-x_n}$$ where $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$, then the answer is $\alpha=2$.

Comment: Can you explain why a = 2 ? Thanks.